# Universal Windows App to Win32 Application

Tags: winapi, win-universal-app

It is probably a stupid question but I was wondering if there was any way to 'convert' a Universal Windows Application to a Win32 Application. I know that's a way to do the opposite so I was curious about it.

Comment: I think the ms not make it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Desktop Bridge you can add Full Trust components to your existing UWP project. The issue is that these are separate processes so if you want to add new "desktop" features you need to coordinate across two processes (or else rewrite your UI in one if the older UI frameworks).

Comment: Also it would be good if you mentioned why you wanted to move to desktop Win32 -- which features are missing?